# Process a form using both Jquery and PHP

Tags: jquery

I am trying to process a form using Jquery and when Javascript is not available (or turned off) in the browser then it should be processed using PHP.

To do this, I've added `action='php_file'` and `onsubmit='myFunction();'` to the form tag.

What it should do:

- When JS is available: `alert("Success!");`
- When JS not available: post data to getdata.php

But when I click on the submit button, the page goes to the PHP file after showing alert box.

You can see the page at http://cgpacalculator.in/

**Edit:**
Here's the form code

```js
<script>
function myFunction(){
        alert("Success!");
}
</script>
```

```html
<form method="post" action="getdata.php" id="calculator" onsubmit="myFunction();">
 <!-- table here -->
 <input class="myButton" type="submit" value="Calculate">
 </form>
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Post your relevant code in your question please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript code to stop form submission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission)

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Doing that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
  ....
 return false; //stop default behaviour

}
```

Comment: You could return what ever you want from `myFunction` and it would not change anything, because the code of the OP is `onsubmit='myFunction();` and  not  `onsubmit='return myFunction();`, and it is not only `//stop default behaviour`  but also stops propagation.